# Dismiss View Controller unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing strange issue regarding **Present** and **Dismiss** ViewController.

For e.g :-

I am at ViewController A then i push to B

So in Navigation Controller Stack we have [A,B]

Now if i present any view controller on B (Like MFMailComposeViewController)

Then after sending mail or deleting draft it dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController and it redirects to A instead of B.

I have researched regarding this but can't find any alternative.

Comment: Can you show the `didFinishWithResult` method of `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`?

Comment: Share the code how you are adding/removing(Push/Pop/Present/Dismiss) NavigationController,A,B and MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

if you have called Popviewcontroller method in  didFinishWithResult method of MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in ViewControllerB, then it could be possible.
instead you avoid PopViewController method call in didFinishWithResult method call.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Use it when you switch between A -> B.

```let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

desiredViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "desiredViewController")

UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController? = desiredViewController ```

Answer (score 0):

try this to presented MFMailComposeViewController from B

```
self.navigationController?.present(MFMailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You might have used

```
self.present(MFMailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do it like this, when you dismiss after sending mail or deleting draft it dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController and after that you can check the ViewController_Identifier if it is 'A_Screen' then avoid it or escape it. Else if, it is 'B-Screen' then navigate to that view controller.

Use this logic to navigate as you want.

```
let targetView: String! = self.restorationIdentifier
    if targetView == "A_Screen"{
                //Do nothing
            }
            else{
    let B_View = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B_Screen") as! BViewController

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(B_View, animated: true)
            }
```

Make sure, that you have set identifierID for your ViewControllers.

Hope it helps you.